# Error: feature 'ImportExport.Import' is disabled. (See M_CUSTOMIZABLE_FUNCTIONALITIES) - SAP HANA

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, erp

Estou usando o SAP BTP Cockpit na versão trial e quero executar um comando SQL para importar um arquivo de armazenamento de dados em csv no meu local para uma tabela que foi criada no Database Explorer com o comando:

```
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE '/home/lucas/"Área de Trabalho"/ssb/sf/ssb-dados-sf1/supplier.csv' INTO "supplier"
WITH
RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'
FIELD DELIMITED BY '|';
```

e tive o seguinte erro:

```
Could not execute 'IMPORT FROM CSV FILE '/home/lucas/"Área de Trabalho"/ssb/sf/ssb-dados-sf1/supplier.csv' INTO ...'
Error: (dberror) [2]: general error: Error: feature 'ImportExport.Import' is disabled. (See M_CUSTOMIZABLE_FUNCTIONALITIES)
```

Tentei rodar o comando:

```
UPDATE  "SYS"."M_CUSTOMIZABLE_FUNCTIONALITIES" 
SET IS_ENABLED= True
WHERE NAME='IMPORTEXPORT.IMPORT';
```

para tentar alterar a permissão para true, mas obtive esse erro:

```
Could not execute 'UPDATE "SYS"."M_CUSTOMIZABLE_FUNCTIONALITIES" SET IS_ENABLED= True WHERE ...'
Error: (dberror) [258]: insufficient privilege: Detailed info for this error can be found with guid '6B521D42F3E0C048BE8FFB6701742D37'
```

Após isso, rodei o comando:

```
CALL SYS.GET_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGE_ERROR_DETAILS ('6B521D42F3E0C048BE8FFB6701742D37', ?)
```

mas ainda continuo sem permissão. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Não conheço SAS mas em geral não se pode atribuir privilégios a si mesmo. Este "get" pela documentação e para se ver os erros.

Comment: Entendi. Então provavelmente esses privilégios seriam concedidos com um upgrade pra uma conta premium?

Comment: Não faria sentido em termos de segurança este "grant". Mas pergunte em alguma comunidade SAP.